# Normal for gdb coredumps to label symbol with incorrect function name when dynamic libraries stripped?

Tags: c++, gdb, elf, coredump

This is the output of me playing around with using 'strip' and various options to try to replicate what I am seeing. Here is a normal backtrace...

```
#0  0x00007f06ff7e96ad in Numbers::AddOne(int) () from libnums.so
#1  0x00007f06ff7e968d in Numbers::AddTwo(int, int) () from libnums.so
#2  0x00007f06ff7e9668 in Numbers::AddThree(int, int, int) () from libnums.so
#3  0x000055ae3a2a67ec in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f06feadac87 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55ae3a2a67ba, argc=1, argv=0x7ffd3e8f5eb8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffd3e8f5ea8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#5  0x000055ae3a2a66da in ?? ()
```

I can verify with 'info sharedlibrary' that I have indeed stripped the binary.

```
0x00007f06ff7e9560  0x00007f06ff7e96b1  Yes (*)     libnums.so
```

But what I am seeing on production coredump files is(before I use 'eu-unstrip' to get debug symbols back) is something like...

```
#0  0x00007f06ff7e96ad in Numbers::SomeFunctionElsewhere() () from libnums.so
#1  0x00007f06ff7e968d in Numbers::MultiplyFive() () from libnums.so
#2  0x00007f06ff7e9668 in Numbers::DivideByZero() () from libnums.so
```

**Notice all function parameter types disappear**

**Just curious if this is totally normal, or potentially indicative of stripping debug symbols incorrectly? Saving debug symbols(in their own file) incorrectly? Or is this a rabbit hole I just need to bypass by recombining .so files with their respective x.so.debug files**

Anything to do with -rdynamic or -fPIC options?

The process in which we strip things out is(legacy code, not mine)

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug $filename  $outFolder/$filename.debug
strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded $filename
# Default links for debug symbol files already exist for libc* and friends.  If you
# don't remove them first, you'll get an "Invalid operation" error
objcopy --remove-section=.gnu_debuglink $filename
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=$outFolder/$filename.debug $filename
```

What I've been using to recombine the files is

```
eu-unstrip x.so x.so.debug -o x.so
```

EDIT: So I managed to create a core dump where it works one way or another. So originally I would execute `info sharedlibrary` to get the start address of where my libraries were loaded to create lines in a .gdbinit file like so...

```
add-symbol-file mylib.so.debug 0xdeadbeef
```

...and that was enough to get line numbers...

```
#0  0x00007f06ff7e96ad in Numbers::AddThree(NO PARAM INFO) () from test.cpp:123
```

I get this exact same behavior when I use eu-unstrip to recombine the debug symbols into their original .so files.

However, if I don't do any of that I won't get line numbers, but I do somehow get my function parameters back

```
    #0  0x00007f06ff7e96ad in Numbers::AddThree(int, int, int) () from libnums.so
```

Upper issue occurred with production code and this edited issue occurred in development, so I'm thinking some shenanigans in our devops env. are likely responsible

Comment: What you described is not normal, and I am having a hard time imagining how it could happen. Do you have a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Not yet sadly, in the process of figuring it out.